# Vector- Sparce Matrix multiplication using MKL

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have simple Fortran code which convert the A=[1,1;1,1] matrix to CSR sparse format and then multiply it with x=(100,200) as a vector, y=A*x.
Unfortunately the result is strange y=(200,200) while it should be y =(300,300) vector. Thanks.

```
program main
implicit none
include 'mkl_spblas.fi'
integer :: nzmax, nnz, job( 8 ), m, n, lda, info, irow, k
double precision :: A(2,2)
double precision, allocatable :: Asparse(:)
integer, allocatable :: ia(:), ja(:)
double precision:: x(2)
double precision:: y(2)

A(1,1) = 1.d0
A(1,2) = 1.d0
A(2,1) = 1.d0
A(2,2) = 1.d0
x(1) = 100.d0
x(2) = 200.d0
!! Give an estimate of the number of non-zeros.
nzmax = 4
print *, "nzmax = ", nzmax

m   = size( A, 1 )   !! number of rows
n   = size( A, 2 )   !! number of columns
lda = m              !! leading dimension of A

allocate( Asparse( nzmax ) )
allocate( ja( nzmax ) )   !! <-> columns(:)
allocate( ia( m + 1 ) )   !! <-> rowIndex(:)

job( 1 )   = 0       !! convert dense to sparse A
job( 2:3 ) = 1       !! use 1-based indices
job( 4 )   = 2       !! use the whole A as input
job( 5 )   = nzmax   !! maximum allowed number of non-zeros
job( 6 )   = 1       !! generate Asparse, ia, and ja as output

call mkl_ddnscsr( job, m, n, A, lda, Asparse, ja, ia, info )
if ( info /= 0 ) then
    print *, "insufficient nzmax (stopped at ", info, "row)"; stop
endif

nnz = ia(m+1)
print *, "number of non-zero elements = ", nnz

do irow = 1, m
    !! This loop runs only for rows having nonzero elements.
    do k = ia( irow ), ia( irow + 1 ) - 1
        print "(2i5, f15.8)", irow, ja( k ), Asparse( k )
    enddo
enddo
call mkl_cspblas_dcsrgemv('n', m, Asparse, ia, ja, x, y)
print*, y
end program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you are using a c-style indexing for calling MKL subroutine.

**mkl_cspblas_dcsrgemv** is zero-based indexing.
for your program you should use **mkl_dcsrgemv** which is one-based indexing.

Comment: Are you shure ut has anything to do with 0-base or 1-base? That would be extremely strange. More likely row-major vs. column major.

Comment: I’m sure since i ran code with mkl_dcsrgemv. Row major and column major is something else. it’s about how arrays are stored in memory and has effect on accessing them in efficient or inefficient way. But here we talk about index. It is somehow the address of value that is stored on the memory. A is defined based on 1 indexing and when you pass this array to zero based routine , since you didn’t give any value to a(0,0) or a(1,0) it assumes that they are zero ( in intel compilers maybe ) , But a(0,1) is a(1,1) and a(1,1) is a(2,1). as a result A=[0,1;0,1] and the result will be (200,200)